Is multiple comparison correct procedure valid in propensity score matching for different outcomes with different matched covariates?
Let's say I have a large dataset. I have 100 outcomes of interest and for each outcomes, there are associated risk factors, which need not be the same for each of them. However, there is a single exposure of binary treatment. (However, I will interpret this as the treatment assignment for particular outcome, rather than a generic treatment for all outcomes.) The goal was to examine whether the treatment is associated with those outcomes after adjusting potential risk factors. Let's assume those risk factors are involve in propensity score estimation as well. I will denote each outcome as $Y_1,\dots,Y_{100}$, treatment assignment variables as $Z_1,Z_2,\dots, Z_{100}$ and outcome associated risk factors as $\vec{X}_1,\vec{X}_{100}$, where $Z_1=Z_2=\dots=Z_{100}$.
Then for each $Y_i,Z_i$ and associated $\vec{X}_i$, I can conduct propensity score matching and obtain a confidence interval of ATE of treatment $Z_i$ or testing significance of treatment effect, where $ATE$ assesses the difference of prevalence of $Y_i$ across corresponding treatment $Z_i$. Let's denote the propensity score matched dataset $D_i$.
Then $D_1,\dots, D_{100}$ need not overlap and of same dimension. In this case, the there is no clear type I error control procedure other than Bonferonni correction, as the tests was not conducted on the same dataset.
$Q:$ Can one do something like FDR/FWER control procedure in this case? Or is there any reason to believe this is valid? The issue is that the p-values were not derived from the same dataset. When one computes $E[FDR]$ or $E[FWER]$, where $FDR$ is proportion of false discovery and $FWER$ is the event of at least 1 type I error, $E[.]$ is applied over dataset sampled from some fixed distribution rather some changing distribution here. (i.e. $D_1,\dots, D_{100}$ need not follow the same joint distribution.)
